# How to give Category type ENTERTAINMENT for android app

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am new to android , so sorry if questions sound stupid
I have created a widget and I want to upload it with category ENTERTAINMENT. In play store there are app with category type ENTERTAINMENT  https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/ENTERTAINMENT?feature=category-nav but I didn't find this defined in category types http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113475. What I need to make it available under ENTERTAINMENT .

How does google know it is a normal app or a widget. I need to do something special or store parses AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

In the developer console v2 (their new look) there is definitely an entertainment category. You do this when you prepare your play store listing. To clarify, this is outside the xml, on the website. [image: Play store listing]

As for widget vs app, just specify it's a widget in the title, the Play Store does not have a specific category for widgets as widgets come as part of an application.